# Can I save an email attachment from Office 365 to a file share with PowerShell?

Tags: email, powershell, fileshare

I've seen several solutions that use PowerShell to automate the local Outlook client but I want this to run server-side: Reach out to the server with a given account, check for unread messages, save any attachments to a file share and mark the message read.

Answer (score 1):

This requires the [Exchange Managed Services API](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35371) to be installed.

```
$ewsPath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
Add-Type -Path $ewsPath

$ews = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService
$cred = (Get-Credential).GetNetworkCredential()
$ews.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential -ArgumentList $cred.UserName, $cred.Password, $cred.Domain
$ews.AutodiscoverUrl( "user@domain.com", {$true} )
$results = $ews.FindItems(
    "Inbox",
    ( New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView -ArgumentList 100 )
)
$MailItems = $results.Items | where hasattachments

foreach ($MailItem in $MailItems){

    $MailItem.Load()

    foreach($Attachment in $MailItem.Attachments){
        $Attachment.Load()
        $File = new-object System.IO.FileStream(("C:\Temp\” + $attachment.Name.ToString()), [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
        $File.Write($attachment.Content, 0, $attachment.Content.Length)
        $File.Close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works great. Could you expand it on how to save only file attachments with a given Extension and the email arriving after a certain date and time (or say every 15minutes to poll for emails)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you in an Exchange environment? If so and Exchange Web Services is exposed to the network that is an option.

Comment: We're in a hybrid Exchange environment. I'm trying to read up on EWS but if you have any quick and dirty PowerShell to connect and pull down the email from a mailbox, that'd be a big help...

Comment: Oh hey I found some code that's working. Seeing now if I can strip off attachments.